# What C/C++ library to use for HTML DOM building/changing?

Tags: c++, c, dom

I am using perl module `HTML::DOM` ([link to CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/~sprout/HTML-DOM-0.044/lib/HTML/DOM.pm)) for building HTML DOM tree from HTML code and then changing it using standard DOM's `removeAttribute`, `removeChild`, `innerHTML`, `createElement` and so on.

But, I have found out it's really, really slow and eating too much memory (it's fully in perl, anyway). So, I thought that there will be some C/C++ library that does it faster and more efficiently (because it happens in every browser that have JavaScript support).

So far, I have not found anything. Maybe I am searching wrong?

edit: I will add. I would like it if it worked similarly to linked Perl module - by that, I really mean so I could use directly HTML's `innerHTML`, `className`, `idName`... Is it posible, or will I need to use general XML parser and then write these by myself?

edit2: OK, the slowness of the Perl module was actually my fault entirely. However, since I already asked, the question still stands :)

Answer (score 3):

[libgdome](http://gdome2.cs.unibo.it/) is a library adding a DOM implementation on top of [libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/).

Many of the faster higher-level language modules for this purpose (such as, in the Python world, [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/)) tend to be built directly on libxml2, doing the DOM bits themselves.

Comment: Thanks. However, I can't find things like "className" or "innerHTML" etc. in the documentation...