# Are there any programming languages other than Javascript that can access and update HTML DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom

I am learning HTML DOM. I am curious if there is any other programming language other than JavaScript that can access and update the content, structure and style of HTML elements through the HTML Document Object Model.

Comment: As of now browsers support only javascript ,except some modern browsers which supports web assembly languages too.

Comment: @Shubh Web assembly cannot access the DOM

Answer (score 2):

There are DOM APIs for just about every programming language out there.

- [C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058025/what-c-c-library-to-use-for-html-dom-building-changing)
- [Perl](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::DOM)
- [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782097/python-is-there-a-built-in-package-to-parse-html-into-dom)
- [Matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/help/rptgen/ug/mlreportgen.dom.html-class.html)

And the list goes on.

---

If you are asking about programming languages supported by web browsers, then [JavaScript is the only practical one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434378/what-client-side-web-scripting-languages-are-there-other-than-javascript-and-vbs) although there are others (TypeScript most notably) which can be transpiled to JavaScript before being sent to the browser.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the DOM in the browser, you must use javascript only.
for example if you want to open popup after user click on some button in your site, only javascript can do it for you because it is client side programming language for browsers.

But if you want to read some HTML page in your program you can do it in any language. the only thing you need is a HTML parser.
for example if you want read products of an online store you can get html text content and then use HTML parser to read it in your programming language.

Answer (score 1):

In the browser? Basically only JavaScript, at least these days.

But many other languages can work with a DOM, or event the browser DOM, like [VBscript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/ms757850(v=vs.100)), [Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/ms766564(v=vs.100)), or [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/dom/index.html) (even [from Applets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/manipulatingDOMFromApplet.html)).